# How do I get a callstack in Haskell?

Tags: debugging, haskell

I am trying to track down a non-exhaustive pattern in a libraries code. Specifically HDBC's mysql implementation. It is trying to match over types in my program and map them to mysql's types I believe. I can't seem to get a callstack for this error which means that since there are a number of parameters to the SQL query it is difficult to track down exactly what is causing it.

Is it possible to get a callstack in haskell so I would know which parameter was causing the error? Also I would think that this should be caught by the compiler since it should be able to look at my types and the patterns and make sure that there was a corresponding match.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [GHCi debugger](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html) to [identify where the exception is coming from](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html#ghci-debugger-exceptions).

I walk through [a full example here](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2007/11/14/no-more-exceptions-debugging-haskell-code-with-ghci/).

Comment: Thanks Don. I have not been able to get that to work due to an issue with ghci not being able to find the dynamic mysql libs. Loading package HDBC-mysql-0.6.2 ... can't load .so/.DLL for: mygcc (dlopen(libmygcc.dylib, 9): image not found)

Comment: You'll probably need to pass the path to the .so file on the command line.

Comment: Got it all fixed up. If you comment out that entry in the cabal file that links in the static lib and then add the dynamic lib path in .bashrc it works. Never got a call stack but once I got the -prof libs for all my dependencies I actually got an informative error.

Comment: ⁺¹ for examples, but the callstack problem probably should addressed here. I'm pretty sure everyone going through the link reading «currently stacktrace not supported». This is not true, and here's how to get it: the command to get stracktrace is `:hist`. But by default it doesn't work. To get it working one have to use command `:trace`, but it by default it doesn't work either. One have to stop the program early *(`:trace` unfortunately launches it)*, enter `:stack`, then on the next stop the `:hist` command would work.

Answer (score 1):

You might also take a look at the [Debug.Trace](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Debug-Trace.html#1) library.

Comment: Although it has nothing to do with a stack trace -- it's a way to print outside of IO.